# Google Map - ImageMapType - Image Pixel to Map Location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am rendering my Building floor Map Image using google Map (Since image size is so large so i need to render it through tiles),

Image Size is approx 7106*4338, Now when i load this large image in google map in (256*256) tiles i need to show Marker on map, i have marker co-ordinates w.r.t image original size (X: 2622, Y:1738), Now i want to map this point to map,

My question is: how to calculate the transform the image point to X,y Point or LatLang Point of Google Map,

Comment: Sorry for the silly question, found the answer its just simple Math problem, i just need to find the scaling factor,

Answer (score 0):

You can convert from Point to Latitude/Longitude like this:

```
var projection = map.getProjection();
var latLng = projection.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point( 2622, 1738 ));
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Projection